# counting recursive calls WITHOUT variables

Tags: java

is it possible to count depth of recursion without variables?

Comment: What do you mean "number of recursive calls"?

Comment: Make your recursive method return statement be in itself the recursive count

Comment: How can you count something without actually `counting`?? You will need a variable to store counts..

Comment: @RohitJain You could potentially store information to external text-files, avoiding having to use actual Java variables.

Comment: Seems like an interview question.

Comment: @user1725578 do you mean with "number of recursive calls" the depth of recursion?

Comment: @A.R.S... OK, how would you access external files without using any variable to reference them?? And actually this would be like using rocks to kill an Ant..

Comment: It should be possible to examine the execution stack without a variable in the recursive method..

Comment: It's really unclear as to what you mean.  Do you mean you can't use a scope-local variable, a global variable?  Can you use a variable inside of the method?  (If you can't this is pretty darn impossible to do.)

Comment: Your question is too vague to give a good answer. Who wants to know this number? The original caller or the function itself? Is "number of recursive calls" the number of times the method has been invoked or the depth of the recursion? What's the method signature look like? Can you change its parameters or return type? What kind of variables _can_ you specify? Can you specify only local variables, or no variables at all? You have given us essentially nothing to work with.

Comment: It would be helpful if the question was rephrased and made clearer. It is clear from the comments that there are some confusion about what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public int foo(int count) {
    if (exitCondition) return count; 
    foo(count+1);
}
```

Other ways of counting invocations would involve reflection or using byte-code modifying libraries (i.e., AoP).

Comment: It's purely functional, and I guess the question is a bit vague on specifics.

Comment: @A.R.S depends on whether you count a method parameter as "variable".

Answer (score 1):

in java,

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

can be used to determine the call depth. the number of recursive calls is the difference between the stack length and the position of the first frame.

or throw an exception and then retrieve the stack from the top-most function with:

```
Throwable.getStackTrace()
```

> Returns an array of stack trace elements, each representing one stack frame. The zeroth element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the top of the stack, which is the last method invocation in the sequence. Typically, this is the point at which this throwable was created and thrown. The last element of the array (assuming the array's length is non-zero) represents the bottom of the stack, which is the first method invocation in the sequence.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely vague, so I'm making a couple of assumptions:

1. By "number of recursive calls" you mean "depth of recursion"
2. The original caller of the function wants to know the depth, so the recursive method returns it
3. By "no variables," this means you can't even use local variables to track the depth

So if you're in some random method and you call your recursive function:

```
public void randomMethod() {
    Something somethingToRecurseOn = ... ;
    int depth = recurse(somethingToRecurseOn);
}
```

This is the expected usage for my solution. Here's the `recurse` method:

```
public int recurse(Something s) {
    Something subS = s.getSubS();
    if (subS == null) { // Exit condition
        return 1;
    }
    // Do something with subS
    return recurse(subS) + 1;
}
```

You integrate the depth into the return value of your function, and assume a depth of 1 for your exit condition.

This is actually relevant to an interview question I've asked in the past, where you have to return the number of elements in a recursive sequence, and the signature is:

```
public int collatz(int n)
```

Where `n` is the number you're operating on to find the next number of the sequence, which stops at 1. If it's implemented with recursion instead of iteration, it essentially returns the recursion depth.